# Como fazer dump automático no MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, dump

Tenho um sistema simples pra gerenciamento de uma loja que por enquanto, na fase de testes, está rodando com servidor local.

Queria saber uma forma de fazer o *dump* da base de dados do MySQL automaticamente no mesmo horário todos os dias (por exemplo: final de tarde) utilizando PHP ou outra sugestão.

Comment: Veja se isso pode te ajudar https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/ ou isto https://www.noupe.com/development/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Olá.

Primeiramente, vai depender do ambiente em que a base de dados esteja.
Se for em um Windows, você pode programar um .bat e agendar sua execução no Agendador de Tarefas. Assim você pode determinar quais os horários que ele será executado. E caso seja em um Linux, a saída é criar um script e agendar a sua execução no crontab. Tanto o Agendador do Windows, quanto o Crontab do Linux, basicamente possuem a mesma funcionalidade. Se sua intenção é utilizar uma linguagem, python é muito interessante e pode te atender muito bem. Mas isso fica a seu critério :)

Lembrando que para ambos os sistemas, o MySQL dispõe de ferramentas para realizar o dump.

Agora deixando de lado a questão do script e do S.O., um fato importante é que você deve pensar muito bem em como irá desenvolver esse código. Um exemplo bem bacana é você programar dois ou três dumps diários, com horários "estratégicos", por exemplo, um no início do dia, outro ao meio dia e o último no fim do dia. Além disso, é importante manter essas cópias por um determinado tempo. Ex: (i) guardar a última cópia do mês de todos os meses, (ii) a última cópia da semana e (iii) as cópias de todos os dias da semana, apagando-as apenas na troca da semana.

Para finalizar, vejo que apesar das cópias, algo muito importante é manter essas cópias replicadas em outro meio, seja um HD externo, uma máquina da rede ou um servidor FTP. Outro fato, é programar uma rotina para validar se as cópias estão íntegras, além é claro, de verificar se elas estão sendo executadas, ou se o arquivo está sendo criado (no linux pode acontecer alguns problemas com permissão de pastas).

Este é um assunto que pode render muito, pouco ou nenhum trabalho, tudo depende da sua preocupação com a segurança dos dados do seu cliente! Comece com algo pequeno, mas procure sempre dar atenção a esse assunto. O Backup só é lembrado quando precisamos dele.